# Tensorflow: I keep getting undefined

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run an analysis with Tensorflow and I keep getting undefined. I attempted to modify my versions and require statements and even refactored knn a bit and nothing I have tried has solved the continued `undefined` as a result.

`testLabels` should be an array of arrays, so I am getting the rows and the dollar value out of there.

```
require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
const loadCSV = require("./load-csv");

function knn(features, labels, predictionPoint, k) {
  features
    .sub(predictionPoint)
    .pow(2)
    .sum(1)
    .pow(0.5)
    .expandDims(1)
    .concat(labels, 1)
    .unstack()
    .sort((a, b) => (a.get(0) > b.get(0) ? 1 : -1))
    .slice(0, k)
    .reduce((acc, pair) => acc + pair.get(1), 0) / k;
}

let { features, labels, testFeatures, testLabels } = loadCSV(
  "kc_house_data.csv",
  {
    shuffle: true,
    splitTest: 10,
    dataColumns: ["lat", "long"],
    labelColumns: ["price"]
  }
);

features = tf.tensor(features);
labels = tf.tensor(labels);

const result = knn(features, labels, tf.tensor(testFeatures[0]), 10);
console.log("Guess", result, testLabels[0][0]);
```

I continue to get this result:

```
Guess undefined 1085000
```

I have console logged all over the place and nothing is returning except the variable `result`:

```
console.log("Guess", result, testLabels[0][0]);
```

So the problem seems to be the `knn` algorithm itself, but I can't figure out what it is.